# output servlet with single quote in single quote

Tags: regex, servlets

I am trying to print out below line in my java servlet with single quotes in single quotes. Tried all available solutions like escaping & adding it under double quote but no luck.

```
out.println("<input type='submit' value='Remove' onclick='this.form.action=/sadmin/servlet/ProcessRequest?action=delete'>");
```

Expected output

```
<input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="this.form.action='/sadmin/servlet/ProcessRequest?action=delete'">
```

Comment: Have you heard of escaping double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of escaping double quotes?

```
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Remove\" onclick=\"this.form.action='/sadmin/servlet/ProcessRequest?action=delete'\">");
```

Comment: Cheers! To be honest, never thought of doing that once.